# Emitting parameterized _Pragma statements?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

It's often undesirable but sometimes unavoidable to emit `#pragma` directives to suppress and restore warnings. Some compilers support `_Pragma` as a way to, among other things, control diagnostics from inside a macro expression.

[How to concatenate strings in the arguments of _Pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762357/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-the-arguments-of-pragma) discusses how to paste a single string into a `_Pragma` statement.

Is there any way to parameterize this? I'd like to combine both `_Pragma` directives behind one macro, but that requires pasting tokens together inside of a `_Pragma` statement:

```
#define DO_A_THING(SOME_FLOAT) \
  do { \
    DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNING(double-promotion) \
    call_variadic_function("blah", SOME_FLOAT) \
    RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNING() \
  } while(0)
```

`DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNING` would expand into something like:

```
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wdouble-promotion\"")
```

and `RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNING` would expand into something like:

```
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```

Is there a way to author `DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNING` to expand out as written?

Comment: Ah, thanks, my sample experiments have the quotes but i typod it when writing this :)

Comment: `that are a combination of multiple tokens?` What are "multiple tokens" and how are they "combined"?

Comment: Thanks, edited to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, edited again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works:

```
// double expand for proper "something \"something\""
#define PRAGMA_DO1(X) _Pragma(#X)
#define PRAGMA_DO(X) PRAGMA_DO1(GCC diagnostic ignored #X)

#define DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNING(X) \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    PRAGMA_DO(-W##X)

#define RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNING()  \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
    
#define DO_A_THING(SOME_FLOAT) \
  do { \
    DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNING(double-promotion) \
    call_variadic_function("blah", SOME_FLOAT); \
    RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNING() \
  } while(0)

void call_variadic_function(const char *str, ...);

int main() {
    // call_variadic_function("blah", (float)1);
    DO_A_THING((float)1);
}
```